# Query with delete is making my table bigger and bigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, sql-delete

I have a table in Redshift with 6 millions of lines, it weight almost 1 GB, and I have a routine that deletes some of the lines and then insert them again (because some of the information change in real-time). But, I dont know why, the table is getting bigger, like REAL bigger, in this weekend it came to weigh almost 100 GB!

When I truncate or drop the table it return to normal (with 1 GB), but I cannot continue to do such thing

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Are you sure that when you delete "old" line it is really deleted? Did you try vacuum cleaning (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Reclaiming_storage_space202.html) ?

Comment: Hello Nikolay, thanks for helping me! When I use VACUUM the table continues with the same storage

Answer (score 1):

When a row is deleted in Amazon Redshift, it is marked as *deleted* but the storage space is only reclaimed after running a `VACUUM` or `VACUUM DELETE` command. This also applies for rows that are Updated, which causes a row to be deleted and then a new row to be added to the end of the storage space.

From [Vacuuming Tables - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Reclaiming_storage_space202.html):

> When you perform a delete, the rows are marked for deletion, but not removed. Amazon Redshift automatically runs a VACUUM DELETE operation in the background based on the number of deleted rows in database tables. Amazon Redshift schedules the VACUUM DELETE to run during periods of reduced load and pauses the operation during periods of high load.

So, your table might not have sufficient "periods of reduced load" to be fully vacuumed.

See also: [VACUUM - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_VACUUM_command.html)

Comment: Hello John, thanks for helping me!
When I use VACUUM the table continues with the same storage (I need to use the VACUUM FULL).
I didn't understand this: "So, your table might not have sufficient "periods of reduced load" to be fully vacuumed." 
How can I set the "periods of reduced load" to use  VACUUM?

Comment: The automatic vacuuming is done during quiet periods. If you have no quiet period, then there might not be any automatic vacuuming. The documentation says: "A DELETE ONLY vacuum is the same as a full vacuum except that it skips the sort. Amazon Redshift automatically performs a DELETE ONLY vacuum in the background, so you rarely, if ever, need to run a DELETE ONLY vacuum."

Comment: Thanks for your reply John!
I can set a time to execute the automatic vacuuming? My routines executes every 30 minutes...

Comment: No, automatic vacuuming is automatic. If you want it to happen at a particular time, you'll need to run it yourself.

Comment: If `VACUUM DELETE ONLY` does not work, you should contact AWS Support.